# Mock UriInfo is not working

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jersey, mockito

I'm trying to setup a couple of unit tests but i'm stuck at this.
This is my service class:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
@Path("/subscriber/{accNo}/case/")
public class ServiceRest {
        @Context
        private UriInfo uriInfo;
        @Autowired
        private ActivationCase actCase;

        @POST
        @Path("activation")
        public Response activate(@PathParam("accNo") String accNo, InputStream jSonInput) {

               Integer order = actCase.activateMethod(accNo);
               Link link = new Link("order", uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path(OrderRest.class).path("" + order).build().toString(), "GET");
        }
}
```

This is  my Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/myapp-context.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
@Ignore
public class ServiceRestTest{
    @Autowired
    private ServiceRest restClient;
    @Autowired
    protected OrderServiceImpl orderService;


    @Test()
    public void testActivationCaseOK() {
        UriInfo uriInfo = Mockito.mock(UriInfo.class);
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = Mockito.mock(UriBuilder.class);
        Mockito.when(uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()).thenReturn(uriBuilder);           
        Mockito.when(orderService.readThings(Mockito.any(Acct.class))).
                       thenReturn(stuff);

        Mockito.when(orderService.maintainPlan(Mockito.any(Order.class))).
                       thenReturn(stuff2);
        Response response = restClient.activateMethod("111111114");
}
```

Can anyone explain me why is uriInfo NULL?
The mock is done, it should have returned my URIBuilder no?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of suggestions worked for me :/
I have to do a workaround.

So , in order to make this work i moved the  **@Context private UriInfo uriInfo**  to be a parameter in each method.

```
 public Response activate(@PathParam("accNo") String accNo, InputStream jSonInput, @Context UriInfo) {
```

And in my unit test:

```
    Mockito.when(uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()).thenReturn(uriBuilder);
    Mockito.when(uriBuilder.path(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(uriBuilder);
    Mockito.when(uriBuilder.build()).thenReturn(uri);
    Response response = restClient.activateMethod("111111114", uriInfo);
```

Thanks for your feedback. I hope this can help somebody in the future

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

(If it's still null then consider changing the Mockito.mock() to @Mock annotations as described here: http://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/spring-and-mockito-happy-together )

Comment: That MockitoAnnotation shouldn't be used only if you have Mocks with annotations?

Comment: i've updated the code like you said and now i have only annotatios.

Comment: But the Uriinfo is still null.. what am I missing?

Comment: Seems it's not initialising it as a mock for some reason.. Just to test, can you change it to run with MockitoJUnitRunner and mock everything?